# In Linux (Ubuntu 10.10 server), can I have a host alias for my IP address and its alias IP's?

Tags: alias, ip-aliasing

I have a web server with realIP 192.168.1.1. Perhaps i'll give it IP aliases 10.1.1.1 and 20.1.1.1.

I have 3 IP subnets in 1 physical network, 10.1.1.0/24, 20.1.1.0/24 and 192.168.1.0/24.

Now what I want to to is I want the users from accross the 3 subnets to be able to access my web server 192.168.1.1 by typing 'OurWebsite' to their browser, instead of an IP address.

Is this possible?

All users don't and cannot be configured to belong to a single domain. I'm just deploying this webserver to the existing infrastructure in a non-invasive way.

Comment: Exactly what Ignacio said, you do not need to do any 'aliasing'. You just need to configure your routers and switches to connect the networks together such that you can access 192.168.1.1 from any of the subnets.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just give it a single address. As long as the default gateways can find the machine, that's what counts.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I was hoping for that. Do I need to deploy some DNS server somewhere in the network, so the users can just type in "OurServer" in their browsers instead of "http://192.168.1.1?"

Comment: If there isn't already one somewhere, yes, with query forwarding. You can get away with dnsmasq if your networks aren't terribly large (<100 clients each), otherwise you'll need BIND.

Comment: Ok. The clients on subnet 192.168.1.0/24 are using DHCP. Perhaps I should just tell the DHCP to give a DNS address (right now it's blank). IP's from the other subnet are manually set on the client pc's. So I guess we'll have to put DNS addresses one by one...